# Mostrar fecha desde el controlador del cliente en la Vista

Tags: angulajs

Yo tengo una serie de datos que traigo desde el controlador del servidor en un MVC.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podéis ver en la imagen, el valor de la fecha llega bien. Cuando lo guardo en el Json para enviarlo tambien se guarda bien.

```html
return new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = data,
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet

            };
```

Pero a la hora de verlo en pantalla me encuentro esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el código HTML simplemente hago el binding pero ya el dato ya ha llegado mal a este punto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<table  class='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre de usuario</th>
                    <th>Rol</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="usuario in data">
                    <td>{{usuario.Nombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{usuario.RolNombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{usuario.EstadoNombre}}</td>
                    <td>{{usuario.FechaAlta}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

A ver si alguien es capaz de echarme una mano... que no sea al cuello :)

---

te voy comentando.

```html
{{usuario.FechaAlta | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```

No me funciona, estoy lo había probado, pero como llega el dato 'mal formado' ya no funciona

```html
{ FechaAlta: $filter('date')(parseInt("/Date(1238540400000)/".substr(6)), 'dd/MM/yyyy') }
```

Esa opción más o menos la había pensado pero como tengo un listado de usuarios tendría que crear un buble para aplicarle el cambio a todos los registros y no es la opción que más me guste.

Y la última opción es lo mismo que esta :(

Ante todo vuelvo a darte las gracias porque son muchas opciones que me das :) Lo único que la idea que tengo es que pudiera tratar el dato que ya me llega desde el HTML si fuera posible, lo mismo no se puede hacer,...

Answer (score 1):

Una opción sería incluir el **[filter date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)** de *AngularJS* después de tu campo **FechaAlta** de la siguiente forma:

```
{{usuario.FechaAlta | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```

o aplicar el mismo **filter** pero en tu controller

```
{ FechaAlta: $filter('date')(parseInt("/Date(1238540400000)/".substr(6)), 'dd/MM/yyyy') }
```

Para esto, debes recordar inyectar `$filter` en el "encabezado" de tu controlador

```
app.controller('$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter){...})
```

En caso que no te funcione debes extraer el int que te genera la fecha y parsearlo mediante una función de la siguiente manera:

```
var date = new Date(tuFecha.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1).toLocaleDateString();
```

Otra solución sería realizar la edición de la fecha sobre el mismo ng-repeat de la siguiente forma:

```
{{tuFecha.slice(6, -2) | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```

*Te menciono que esta última opción la extraje de **[acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16104960/correctly-format-asp-net-mvc-dates-for-angularjs)**, en el cual también se da una excelente alternativa de crear una directiva para el manejo de fechas provenientes de MVC*

Nos comentas que tal te va =)

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le ocurre lo que a a mi, de momento a la hora de traer el dato desde la base de datos, en vez de guardarlo en un Datetime lo he guardado como un string con el formato 'dd/MM/yyyy' y con eso si me funciona.

```html
objeto.FechaAlta = DateTime.Parse(row["FechaAlta"].ToString());
objeto.FechaAltaTexto = objeto.FechaAlta.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Poco recomendable, ya que añades funcionalidad innecesaria - _desde mi punto de vista obviamente_ - al realizar un trabajo en tu `back` cuando perfectamente lo puedes trabajar desde el lado del cliente. Claramente si decidas utilizar esta alternativa es completamente respetable :)